# AttributeError when pulling data from Cryptocompare API

Tags: python, json, request

I am using this function to pull data from the Cryptocompare website into a pandas dataframe:

```
def daily_price_historical(symbol, comparison_symbol='USD', limit=1, aggregate=1, exchange='', allData='true'):
    url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym={}&tsym={}&limit={}&aggregate={}&allData={}'\
        .format(symbol.upper(), comparison_symbol.upper(), limit, aggregate, allData)
    if exchange:
        url += '&e={}'.format(exchange)
    page = requests.get(url)
    data = page.json()['Data']
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['timestamp'] = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(d) for d in df.time]
    df.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)
    df['symbol'] = symbol
    df['1dret'] = 100* df['close'].pct_change()
    return df
```

This works fine for most symbols I pass in, but when I loop over a longer list of symbols I get the error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'time'

I assume this is due to the API returning an error for certain symbols, e.g.:

https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=FAKE&tsym=USD

returns "Response":"Error" with no further data

I'm afraid I'm not very experienced with url requests/APIs. Is there code I can add to the function to skip the symbols that are causing the issue?

Thanks for your help!

---

Additional information:

Code used to loop over coins (which is a list of 130 symbols):

```
price_columns = ['close', 'high', 'low', 'open', 'time', 
'volumefrom','volumeto', 'symbol', '1dret']
top_coin_prices = pd.DataFrame(columns=price_columns)

for coin in coins:
    output = daily_price_historical(coin)
    top_coin_prices = top_coin_prices.append(output)
```

Full Traceback:

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-277-126f5d1686b2> in <module>()
      8 # populate df with data for all coins
      9 for coin in coins:
---> 10     output = daily_price_historical(coin)
     11     top_coin_prices = top_coin_prices.append(output)
     12 

<ipython-input-111-65b3fa76b4ab> in daily_price_historical(symbol, comparison_symbol, limit, aggregate, exchange, allData)
      7     data = page.json()['Data']
      8     df = pd.DataFrame(data)
----> 9     df['timestamp'] = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(d) for d in df.time]
     10     df.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)
     11     df['symbol'] = symbol

/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   2968             if name in self._info_axis:
   2969                 return self[name]
-> 2970             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   2971 
   2972     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'time'
```

Comment: Please add the full traceback and not just the error

Comment: I assume it comes from `df['timestamp'] = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(d) for d in df.time]` and I guess that JSON response doesn't have a `time` column.

Comment: Thanks @roganjosh - I have added the full traceback above. The issue however arises also if I change the column to another metric, e.g. 'close'. Thanks very much for your help!